# How to tackle JavaScript powered dynamic form

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a hobbyist Django project. I feel comfrtable with both Python and Django, but I rarely use JavaScript, and mostly it ends after loading and initializing the library.
This time I want to tackle it a bit more, I have a good task, but I don't even know how to tackle it correctly.

I want to build something like this, with the main functionality being clicking on available statuses, and then 'painting' given hour blocks with them. After that you hit save, and it saves the data via Django

[image]

Conceptually I have an idea how to make this, but I don't know where to start. Should I use some kind of framework? Is there any plugin that could help me with this? Should I put this all into some kind of JS library?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started knocking something up which is a good starter for 10 - have a look on JSFiddle. I can't do any more, as I've got to shoot off now.

I'd basically go for minimal markup, and have everything as a component.

I'd recommended including [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to handle your layout (grids), and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to write less/do more with JS.

I wouldn't start with a framework - the thing you're doing is (fairly) noddy, and you'll do a fine job writing it yourself. You might want to check out [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) to help out with some drag functionality.

General advice - read up about [JS design patterns](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=js%20design%20patterns).

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/nxwytdqw/

Comment: Thanks a LOT, that should be enough to get me started : )